# Code::Blocks correctly finds but fails to open standard includes

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 IDE on Xubuntu 14.04 for writing C and C++ code, and in spite of correctly finding header files by the compiler, the IDE is not capable to automatically open included outside of the project tree files with "Open include file" command, including standard headers.

Is there any C::B configuration with which is possible to work around this limitation? Maybe some plugin providing functionality similar to Qt Creator "Include Hierarchy" feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the "Code completion" plugin which is resolved after plugin is disabled and enabled again from the "Manage Plugins ..." dialog.